# Setting a variable dynamically in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

Is it possible for me to dynamically determine a field name or variable, e.g.

```
module ApplicationHelper
def current_week
  1
end

Controller
def @player = Player.find(params[:id]) 

/item/show.html.erb
<%= @player.total_for_week_{current_week} %>
```

This way I can update the current_week variable, either manually or based on a formula, and have it flow to all of my views. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= @player.send("total_for_week_#{current_week}") %>
```

Comment: This will work, but it strikes me as hackish and probably more complicated than it needs to be.  Can't you just have a method on player called `total_for_current_week`?  Then have that method reference your current_week variable directly?  Part of it is a question of who should keep track of the current_week.